# Optimizing timeseries manipulation without loops: is it possible?

Tags: r, time-series

The problem is simple: a temporal aggregation of univariate data. A generic example:

```
x <- seq(from=as.Date('2000-01-01'),by='1 day',length.out=10^6)
y <- runif(10^6)
xy <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

x.mean <- seq(from=as.Date('2000-01-15'),by='1 month',length.out=30000)
y.mean <- rep(NA,30000)
xy.mean <- data.frame(x=x.mean,y=y.mean)

for(i in 1:29999)
{
  read.mean <- xy.mean[i,1] <= xy[,1] & xy[,1] < xy.mean[i+1,1]
  xy.mean[i,2] <- mean(xy[read.mean,2])
}
```

Instead of days and months, I could have minutes, years, weeks or decades. My code works, but is too slow. How can I speed up the process? I know xy.mean[,1] and I need to calculate xy.mean[,2].

If you suggest to use a package, I would like to understand *how* the package is speeding up the process.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere a loop will always be needed to deal with such problems. The trick is to do the loop not in R but in a much faster, lower level language like C. I believe that is also the way many packages increase speed.

In this case you can also do it without additional packages:

1. Use the function `findInterval` to assign a "group index" to all rows of `xy`. So if `xy$x` is smaller than `xy.mean$x` it gets index 0, if its between the first and second row of `xy.mean$x` it gets 1 and so on.
2. Use `tapply` to compute the mean per group.

   ```
    x <- seq(from=as.Date('2000-01-01'),by='1 day',length.out=10^6)
    y <- runif(10^6)
    xy <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)


    x.mean <- seq(from=as.Date('2000-01-15'),by='1 month',length.out=30000)

    group <- findInterval(xy$x, x.mean)

    y.mean <- tapply(xy$y, group, mean)

    ## I'm not sure if you'd like to delete the first or the last group
    ## I believe the old code deleted the last group, so I did it this way
    xy.mean <- data.frame(x=x.mean,y=y.mean[-length(y.mean)])
   ```

Comment: your answer is perfect. Thank you so, so much, I did not know the function findInterval.